# Get real X and Y coordinates of WebView

Tags: android, webview

I have a simple Android application which should draw circles in WebView at the point of user's touch. This was pretty simple. With the use of OnGestureListener and a proper formula consisting of e.getX()/Y and WebView's getScrollX() and getScale() I could draw a circle exactly at the point of touch.

The problems, however, emerged when adding a TextView and Button above the WebView. These created an offset for the getX and getY values (actually, just getY() :D ). Thus, the application is drawing the circles lower than desired. What is the best way to remove this offset? Or, what is the best way to get the actual position on the WebView (regardless of surrounding UI)?

I was thinking about simply subtracting some constant value, but due to the large variety of screen sizes, densities and Android versions used (plus, sizes of text, etc.) this would not solve my problem for all the devices.

[image: drawing of the problem]

Comment: Yes, although not entirely correct, it pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with subtraction height of Textview and Button

```
int heightofTextView=yourTextView.getLayoutParams().height;
int heightofButton=yourButtonView.getLayoutParams().height;
int TouchYofWebview=webview.getY();
int orignalY = TouchYofWebview - (heightofTextView+heightofButton);
```

Comment: getLayoutParams().height gave me incorrect results, but thanks to you I have found myTextView.getHeight(), which solved my problem. So, thank you, you pointed me in the right direction and I will give you deserved credit for that.